# Swift 4 tableview pagination for api data

Tags: swift, uitableview, pagination

I'm receiving data from server, 10 items per request and need to implement pagination to do request when user scroll to bottom and add new data to the old data at tableview and every time I send request I send increase 1 to number of page that's a part of response for pagination

```
"total_items": 10,
     "current_page": 1
```

and that is the code I tried  with:

```
var pageNo:Int=1
var limit:Int=10
var totalPages:Int=10
var myAds = [MyAds]()

 func current(pageNo:Int) {
    API.myCurAds(pageNo: pageNo, completion: { (error: Error?, data:[MyAds]?) in
        if data != nil {
        self.myAds = data!
        self.tableView.reloadWithAnimation()
            print("myAds", data!)
        }
    })
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == myAds.count - 1 { //
        if  pageNo < totalPages {
            pageNo += 1
            self.current(pageNo: pageNo)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always replacing current data with new fetched data, you need to be append in it.

<s>`self.myAds = data!`</s>

instead of this you need to append new data in existing one.

```
self.myAds.append(contentsOf: data!)
```